# Would honey and molasses be liquids or sugars in a bread formula?

Tags: bread

If 60-85% is the percentage range for the liquid amount in a bread formula, and 0-10% for the sugar amount, my question would be if you are using honey and molasses in the formula would they be counted towards the liquid portion or the sugar portion?

Comment: Doesn't sugar traditionally count as a wet ingredient in baking?

Comment: @KateyΨ depends http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/564/why-is-sugar-a-wet-ingredient

Comment: @Katey in batters, the order of incorporation matters. There, sugar is added to the "wet" half, because 1) you want to dissolve crystal sugar in a liquid and 2) it gives you more air when creamed with butter or whipped with the eggs. Also notice that "wet" and "liquid" is not the same, also outside of cooking: "dry" cleaning is done with a liquid chemical. When used precisely, "liquid" should be a phase of matter, and "wet" means that the thing is capable of giving off water. But this precision is not usual in recipes.

Comment: Conclusion of my previous comment: In baking, "wet" vs. "dry" is not the same as "liquid" vs something else (usually flour, but also some bulking ingredients). The first is about order of mixing, the second is about ratio.

Answer (score 11):

They are definitely counted towards the sugar.

The simple part of the answer is hydration. The primary purpose of the liquid in dough is to hydrate the starch in the flour. Honey and molasses are pure sugars and contain no water. Even though their phase is liquid, they shouldn't be counted as a liquid for making bread. You can't hydrate a starch with sugar.

In fact, the "liquid" part in the bread formula should mean water. There are breads made with liquids other than water (e.g. milk), but these liquids are mostly water with something dissolved in it. A liquid with no water in it doesn't count at all for hydration. This includes honey and oil.

The more complex answer should consider two other effects of liquid  in the bread formula. First, there is the dough consistency. Bread is about texture. A liquid dry ingredient will not hydrate the flour, but it will still reduce the viscosity of your dough. Big amounts of it will make a very soft dough which doesn't keep its shape well, has a big oven spring, and in general doesn't behave like classic lean dough. So a recipe containing lots of such an ingredient will still need an adjustment of the amount of hydrating liquid (like water) even though the ingredient (like honey) is considered dry.

The second effect of adding a dry liquid ingredient is that it will make your bread softer. First, you are introducing new molecules into the dough, which keep the gluten strands from finding each other. So you get a less sturdy gluten formation, resulting in a more cakelike bread (yes, cake *is* cakelike because it has sugar and fat). Also, baked bread loses water over time and gets hard, but sugar binds some of the lost water, and fat prevents the evaporation of the water. A stale enriched (=containing fat and sugar) bread is still stale, but very different in texture from a stale lean bread. So again, you might still want to adjust the amount of hydrating liquid downwards a bit because of this effect your dry ingredient will have on your recipe (or maybe not, if you view the effect as desirable).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response, I will certainly adjust to that effect. Thank you again Lisa

Comment: Honey is a good 17% water. It is very hygroscopic so it will help moisturize otherwise dry bread by pulling moisture from the air. Because of these things it can't always be substituted for sugar without adjusting the water in the recipe.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey http://www.epicurious.com/articlesguides/howtocook/primers/breadingredients

Comment: To be clear- I agree with everything else in this answer.

Comment: Minor nitpick, cake is also cakelike because it uses low-gluten flour. Sometimes milled differently (e.g., finer), too.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I will take them all into consideration upon fine tuning my whole wheat sandwich bread recipe.

Comment: @derobert Not in Europe - there is no "cake flour" here and I can assure you that our cakes are cakelike. We don't get flour graded by gluten content, and some types of wheat popular in North America are not grown here at all. But if you do use cake flour, this is of course a factor which changes texture.

Comment: @Sobachatina - in Peter Reinhart's formulas, which don't fail me, sugar and honey are a 1-to-1 substitute.  Bread dough can handle a certain amount of variance in the wetness, which is seen by most recipes showing a range for liquid amounts.

Comment: @justkt that's not the same thing as "contains no water", though.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally discovered a softer bread by adding honey. I forgot to reduce the water and had to add at least a cup (or so) of flour to stiffen it back up again. I never did get the former feel of the dough (making bread) but it turned out better (and softer) than expected. I still used sugar, but not as much as before.  An accidental discovery.